# Puppet - How to override a class when using inheritance?

Tags: class, inheritance, overriding, puppet

I'm using Puppet to manage my CentOS servers.

Every server inherits from the node 'common':

```
node 'common' {
    class { 'ssh:server':
        permit_root_login => no,
    }

    #[...] Other useful classes I want to keep
}

node default inherits 'common' {}
```

I'd like to keep the useful 'common' node but to override the SSH part for only ONE server:

```
node 'host.domain.com' inherits 'common' {
    class { 'ssh:server':
        permit_root_login => yes,
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one reason node inheritance is generally frowned up. In any case the best strategy here is to use a variable for the `permit_root_login` value, and then use inheritance to initialize the variable value either through hiera or perhaps environment init.pp's.

So in the case of hiera your manifest would look like:

```
node 'common' {
    class { 'ssh::server':
        permit_root_login => hiera('is_permit_root_login_enabled'),
    }
}

node 'host.domain.com' inherits 'common' {}
```

Then in your global.yaml hiera file you'd have:

```
is_permit_root_login_enabled: "no"
```

Then in your override yaml, `host.domain.com.yaml`:

```
is_permit_root_login_enabled: "yes"
```

I recommend using hiera because it's built with this kind of inheritance in mind and has very flexible inheritance strategies.